# Calculating a function of contiguous states with dplyr without using group_by?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
States <- data.frame(State = c('a','a','b','c','c','a','b'),Duration = c(2,3,5,4,7,2,1))
```

I want to find the duration this system spends in each visit to a state.  That is, I want

```
State  Duration
a       5
b       5
c      11
a       2
b       1
```

The quick answer uses group_by, but it is wrong;

```
States %>% group_by(State) %>% summarise(Total = sum(Duration))
```

gives

```
   State Total
  (fctr) (dbl)
1      a     7
2      b     6
3      c    11
```

How would you do that?

Thanks,

Bill

Here's a simpler version that may be closer to the essence of my problem.

```
States <- data.frame(State = c('a','a','a','b','c','c','b','a','b','d'),Duration = c(0,2,2,3,0,5,4,7,2,1))

     States
   State Duration
1      a        0
2      a        2
3      a        2
4      b        3
5      c        0
6      c        5
7      b        4
8      a        7
9      b        2
10     d        1
```

I do want to sum up the duration spent in contiguous visits to the states.  For this case, that's

```
a 2
b 3
c 5
b 4
a 7
b 2
d 1
```

In other words, you take the last duration for each state visit, and the first duration is 0 if there is more than one entry for that visit (I didn't design the data; I'm simply working with it).

If I use group_by as above, dplyr resorts the data frame by State, and that gives me the wrong answer: one entry per state, not one entry per visit.

Does that help?  I think they're both related: is there a way to aggregate rows without rearranging them?

Comment: @DatamineR ah - I read it as the second code chunk is the desired result, the third chunk is what he's tried, and the fourth code chunk is the output of his incorrect attempt.

Comment: To clarify, the first code block creates the input data.  The second shows what I want.  The third shows the wrong code using group_by, and the fourth shows the result of the wrong code.  I am seeking code that produces the second code block.  @tospig, you are correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a new grouping variable, using run length encoding.  I'm sure there's a more dplyr-ish way to do some of these steps.

```
rles <- rle(as.character(States$State))
States$new.groups <- rep(LETTERS[seq_along(rles[[1]])], rles$lengths)

durations <- States %>% group_by(new.groups) %>%
               summarise(Total = sum(Duration)) %>% 
               transform(States = new.groups, new.groups = NULL)

durations$State <- rles$values # assign the appropriate values to duration$State

#Source: local data frame [5 x 2]
#
#   State Total
#   (chr) (dbl)
#1      a     5
#2      b     5
#3      c    11
#4      a     2
#5      b     1
```

---

If you're OK with incorporating a `data.table` function, you can use the very nice `rleid` for slightly cleaner looking code:

```
library(data.table)
States$new.groups <- rleid(States$State)

    durations <- States %>% group_by(new.groups) %>%
               summarise(Total = sum(Duration)) %>% 
               transform(States = new.groups, new.groups = NULL)

durations$States <- rle(as.character(States$State))$values  # still had to use regular rle here
```

Comment: rle, a very interesting function that I did not know.

Comment: @PereG it's an awesome function.  Actually, `data.table`'s `rleid` function might actually be even better for this task!

Comment: Thanks!  Both solutions seem to head in a useful direction, but I like the rleid() suggestion best so far.  I kept looking for a dplyr-ish solution and didn't know about rle() or rleid().

Answer (score 1):

Calculate a dummy variable

```
for (i in 1:(dim(States)[1]-1)){
      States$new[1] <- "A"
      States$new[i+1] <- ifelse(States$State[i] == States$State[i+1], 
            States$new[i], 
            LETTERS[i]
      )      
}
```

build the new data.frame and format it

```
data <- data.frame(cbind(as.character(unique(States$State)), rowsum(States$Duration, States$new)))
names(data) <- c("State", "Duration")
rownames(data) <- NULL
data
```

It isn't an elegant code, but with your data, it works.

---

To achieve the proposed solution after editing:

```
States2 <- States[States$Duration != 0,]
```

Now, the same for-loop

```
for (i in 1:(dim(States2)[1]-1)){
      States2$new[1] <- "A"
      States2$new[i+1] <- ifelse(States2$State[i] == States2$State[i+1], 
                                States2$new[i], 
                                LETTERS[i]
      )      
}
```

And a new block of code:

```
library(data.table)
States2 <- as.data.table(States2)
# set "new" as the key variable
setkey(States2, new)     
# select the last row of new
States3 <- as.data.table(States2[unique(States2$new), mult = "last"])
# clean the data
States3[, new := NULL]
States3
```

[image]